# initiating a call to php file in a java servlet

Tags: java, php, servlets

I have a php page that only has print statement. I want to initiate
a call to this PHP file inside a Java servlet so that it will output the print statement and i can change the colors there

this is the code i tried in the servlet:

```
try
{
    process = runtime.exec("php " + "C:/xxamp/htdocs'/nouf.php nouf" + " nouf");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    out.println("<h4>Runned!</h4>");
}
```

but nothing gets displayed, not the print statement nor the exception

Comment: PHP gets served through web server, you need to standup a apache server make it serve PHP page and make a HTTP request from Java

Comment: i put my php file already in htdocs, which http should i request, and should it be inside runtime.exec("")?

Comment: google and read about `http client for java`